# Select a random value from file while limiting selection to first 5 entries

Tags: php

I have a text file that contains 50 lines/entries. I want to select a random value only from the first 5 lines/entries not the whole file.
for example, if the file had 7 entries:

```
1. Orange
2. Banana
3. Apple
4. Peach
5. Mango
6. Berries
7. Pineapple
```

the output should be one of first 5 items.

My code so far is selecting a random from the whole file, its not limiting the selection.

```
$filename = file("/home/file.txt"); 
echo $read_filename = $filename[rand(0, count($$filename) - 1)];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You over-complicated it.  Simply:

```
<?php
$lines = file("/tmp/fruits.txt");
echo $lines[rand(0, 4)]; // display one of the first 5 lines.
```